# Import Excel data into UWP Windows

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have tried using DataGrid and ListView but no result. How can I read 
Excel file into my UWP Windows application? Please help.

Comment: provide more information what you have tried so far that will help to understand your issue far better

Comment: I tried ListView. But for some reasons, my VS15 UWP Windows 8.1 cannot allow System.Data reference and give architecture error.

Please, Do you have or know any way I can read excel file into UWP without downloading from Nugget, because that's also giving errors.

Thanks.

Comment: “VS15 UWP Windows 8.1”, What's actually you are developing ,uwp app or windows 8.1 app

Comment: **UWP** I working on the Windows (Windows 8.1) part.

Comment: we would need some more information. Reading data != Listview; if you have xlsx files you can read/ and parse it on your own

Comment: Okay. 
Can I get codes or resources on how to read a CSV file or xlsx into ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt683802. It also links to the Author GitHub account for CSV.

Thanks.